# Web-extension code to download file works in Chrome but fails in Firefox with 'illegal characters' error?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

This code, in my web-extension background script works fine in `Google Chrome` but not in `Firefox`. The error I get is:

`Unchecked lastError value: Error: filename must not contain illegal characters`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    var url = message.url;
    var fname = message.filename;
    fname = fname.replace(/[\\\/:"*?<>|\r\n]+/g, "_");

    chrome.downloads.download({
        url: url,
        filename: fname,
        conflictAction: 'uniquify',
        saveAs: true
    });
});
```

Checked the filename via `console.log` to be a valid string. Removing the `filename: fname` line makes it work in firefox but without my desired filename.

**EDIT:** Results of `console.log("fname = " + fname);` followed by `console.log(fname.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).filter(c => c < 32 || c > 127))`
[image: Console.log]

Comment: Might be a bug in Firefox. Could you show the actual file name here? Also check if there's a non-ASCII symbol by running console.log(fname.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)).filter(c => c < 32 || c > 127)) - maybe there is some weird uncode symbol in there.

Comment: Yes, the code was working fine and it seems Firefox update triggered this. Will share the above code results with you when I access my PC.

Comment: All filenames are failing, but here is one I am using for testing `Little Richard -2000-  Directed by Robert Townsend  Starring Leon Jennifer Lewis.mp4`.

Comment: Maybe the full path+name exceeds 260 characters which is a limit in Windows? There is an internal workaround so maybe Firefox stopped using it.

Comment: No it seems a bug, getting rid of double spaces fixes the issue!!

Comment: `-2000-  Directed` when changed to `-2000- Directed` fixes the issue. Any ideas why? EDIT: The first one has 2 spaces but stack if trimming it to one in comments. Also, using `.replace(/\s+/g,' ');` fixes the issue/bug. Do you think this is `Firefox` bug?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this constitutes an answer but, this is now a confirmed bug in Firefox - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1637973